# Regression - many values of DV per value of IV

Tags: regression

I am measuring "loss of memory events" for a sequence of blocks as a function of the distance that separates the first block in the sequence from the last block.

There are many observations. For each observation the dependent variable (loss of memory events) can take three values: no block was forgotten (0), one block was forgotten (1), two blocks were forgotten (2).

For one value of the independent variable there are many values of the dependent variable (one per observation). E.g. for a distance of 70mm, in one trial 1 block was forgotten, in another 2, etc

Is it possible to regress loss_of_memory_events on distance? (available: 71 observations)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is no requirement for every case in a regression problem to have a unique set of IVs.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/103153)

Comment: Actually it is each value of the IV that can have many values of the DV. Each block sequence has a unique distance between first and last block. But different people reproduced the sequence. Therefore, for each time a sequence is reproduced memory loss_of_memory_events have a different value (either 0, 1 or 2). Is a regression OK then?

Comment: @John This was a direct answer to "Is it possible to regress loss_of_memory_events on distance?", with an explanation.

Comment: @Gwen Actually, we would usually frame this sort of scenario as several observations with identical IV values (block distance) and possibly different DVs (memory performance). The complication you didn't mention in your original post is that not all of your 71 observations are from the same person, nor are they all from different people. You can handle this grouping (of trials, by subject) with a mixed model, where each subject gets their own random effect.

Comment: For a given sequence, there are several responses from different subjects. But responses cannot be nested within participant because each participant produced only one response for that sequence.Example: Sequence A. Distance: 70mm. There are four trials, from four different persons. So, for the IV value of 70 there are four values of DV: 0, 1, 2, 0. The aim of the analysis it to assess whether distance predicts loss-of-memory-events (the hypothesis is that as distance gets shorter, loss_of_memory_events increases). Would a simple regression be a good analysis? Thanks!

Comment: Each participant producing only one response per sequence is not an obstacle to using a mixed model. The random effects will still be identifiable because each subject also responded to other sequences. Don't use ordinary least squares (i.e., simple regression) because trials were not sampled independently because of the grouping by subjects. Use a mixed model instead.

Comment: Thanks Kodiologist, hopefully I clicked on the right item.